# Can I make software for Christian school?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, software

I AM  required to make a software for christian school and they have bible subject included. Should I make it?

Comment: You're allowed to. Otherwise with such a logic selling milk to an atheist/kafir is considered a sin and shouldn't be done. But we know that's allowed.

Answer (score -1):

If you make software for them, then you are Directly promoting Shirk and Kufr ( Christians do Kufr and Shirk by associating others with Allah). So you cannot support them in spreading or supporting teachings of bible.

Comment: Thank you, but the are not teaching bible and I am not supporting them teaching. They are teaching normal subjects and bible is one of them. And my job is to calculate results. Only a number to be calculated, no any direct promotional.. Software is for calculating scores of 10 normal subjects and one for bible...

Comment: in that case i would suggest to consult an authentic scholar. as i dont know about it. its better to stay away (until you are not sure about exact ruling) to be on safe side.